# Permutation password with or in the question

Tags: probability, permutations

Here is a question I think there is a red robin it says all uppercase `or` lowercase

> A password on a certain computer system is known to be composed
>   entirely of upper or lower case alphabetic letters without repetition.
>
> If the password is eight characters long, what is the probability of
>   randomly guessing the password?

My solution would be as follows 26P8 = 6.2999(Big number)

This is because the user must choose between 26 upper `or` lowercase characters

Answer (score 1):

You lost the exponent on $26P8$.  The value (even if the exponent is supplied) is not [quite correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=26%21%2F18%21)-there is a zero after the first two $9$s. You should also multiply by $2$ because you get to choose the case of the first letter-all the rest must follow that choice.  Finally, the probability should be less than $1$, so you need to take the inverse.